# What is the most common target version in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

What is the "acceptable" target API level for new iOS apps? I'm starting iOS dev and I'd like to know what version should I target.

I come from Android and there the target 2.1+ covers about the 98% and 2.2+ a 90% of the actual devices in the market. [[Related link]](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)

Where are those levels in iOS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not exist statistic for that on iOS, but since there aren't that much different devices for iOS it isn't that hard. Most people are alway's using the two latest versions and a few people still use older versions because their hardware isn't supported by the newest versions. Have a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_version_history#Current_versions

At the moment I would recommend to supports versions 4.2+ and you will fit the devices of most users.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of factors here... target audience, APIs/memory your app requires, amount of time you want to dedicate to debugging/coding around older versions.

Everything below applies to *right now*. In 6 months it'll likely be different logic.

If your app doesn't require special APIs or a ton of memory and you have the time it might be best to shoot for iOS 4+. This includes a few devices that can't upgrade to iOS 4.3 (iPhone 3G and iPod Touch 2nd gen). If that is too much work, 4.3+ is a good target for recent devices and security updates. If you absolutely need iOS 5 APIs, then target iOS 5.

This link isn't totally authoritative, but it's a good example of a segment of the iOS-toting population's upgrade spread: [Instapaper stats](http://www.marco.org/2011/11/30/more-ios-device-and-os-version-stats-from-instapaper).

Answer (score 2):

till the time you will be ready to have a good app in the app store.. iOS 5 will be majority in the market..